# When would I use a routing slip over a state machine

Tags: c#, masstransit

I can’t wrap my head about the 2 concepts being different, when I need a distributed transaction or event business logic my mind always goes to using a state machine. I know routing slips are useful but I can’t really know when to use one.

My question is, when would I need to use one over the other? Or why use a state machine to track the state of a routing slip and not just manage state and use the state machine? I can’t really tell when to use one or the other

Comment: There is a video coming out later this week on my [YouTube Channel](https://www.youtube.com/@PhatBoyG) that will discuss that very subject.

Comment: @ChrisPatterson you are awesome, love your videos. Watched all season 2 and season 3, that’s why I started loving state machines and got confused about the switch to routing slip. Thanks a lot Chris you are the man.

Answer (score 1):

A state machine only tracks one state at a time, and that state could have any number of potential exits. If you think of the Mario Brothers games, big Mario could get a fire flower, or a leaf/tail, or a star/invincibility, or get shrunk, or fall in a pit and die. Those are all new states that could transition from the big Mario state.

Routing slip requires a linear set of processes or actions that are fixed from the start. Outgoing mail goes to the origin mailbox (where the flag gets raised), to the origin post office (to be aggregated with all other outgoing mail), to the sorting facility (to choose the destination post office), to the destination post office (to select the route to the destination mailbox), and then to the destination mailbox.

You can't skip any of those steps. You can't do them out of order. There aren't multiple potential exits at each step along the way.